# calll click event of a button of aspx page from usercontrol

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i have a button in an usercontrol.

```
  <asp:Button ID="btnCompare" CssClass="new_btn" runat="server"
  Text="Compare" />
```

i need to call a click event of a button which is in another aspx page on "btnCompare" button click.

is it possible ?

Comment: I would recommend redirecting to the other page with myPage.aspx?compare=true and on the page load check the query string, if it is set to true then call the same function that is called from your btnCompare click event?

Comment: Is the button on the same page as the UserControl is, or it is on another page?

Answer (score 0):

You can keep that event handler in a js file, which you can use in both the files, or in any file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. You can try achieve this with javascript event handling

**Edit:** From my understanding you are trying to click a button on a page in which the user control also placed.

Usually what I do is invoke a JavaScript event from user control that actually fires the page button click.

**Example Code In Page.aspx**

```
 function FirePageLevelOkButton(){
  var okButton= document.getElementById('<%=btnOk.ClientID %>');
  if(okButton){ 
   okButton.click(); // if you have ok button in page you can fire click, 
     //this will execute codebehind code
  }
 }
```

**In User Control**

```
   <asp:Button ID="btnCompare" CssClass="new_btn"  runat="server"  
    OnClientClick="javascript:FirePageLevelOkButton();" Text="Compare" />
```

Hope this would help you!